# How to train Keras model with Image AND separate value as input? Mixed input

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am building a reinforcement learning agent for my autonomous copter. My Keras (1.0.7) model for pure image input looks like this:

```python
image_model = Sequential()
image_model.add(Convolution2D(32, 8, 8, subsample=(4, 4), input_shape=(1, 120, 215)))
image_model.add(Activation('relu'))
image_model.add(Convolution2D(64, 4, 4, subsample=(2, 2)))
image_model.add(Activation('relu'))
image_model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, subsample=(1, 1)))
image_model.add(Activation('relu'))
image_model.add(Flatten())
image_model.add(Dense(512))
image_model.add(Activation('relu'))
image_model.add(Dense(nb_actions))
image_model.add(Activation('linear'))
```

In order to learn properly I have to pass some additional values to my model besides the pure image (orientation, position of my copter etc.). I guess I have to streams of network architecture that result in one single output layer or several output layers.

```python
image_model = Sequential()
image_model.add(Convolution2D(32, 8, 8, subsample=(4, 4), input_shape=input_shape))
image_model.add(Activation('relu'))
image_model.add(Convolution2D(64, 4, 4, subsample=(2, 2)))
image_model.add(Activation('relu'))
image_model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, subsample=(1, 1)))
image_model.add(Activation('relu'))
image_model.add(Flatten())
image_model.add(Dense(512))
image_model.add(Activation('relu'))


value_model = Sequential()
value_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=values))
value_model.add(Dense(16))
value_model.add(Activation('relu'))
value_model.add(Dense(16))
value_model.add(Activation('relu'))
value_model.add(Dense(16))
value_model.add(Activation('relu'))



model = Sequential()

#merge together somehow

model.add(Dense(nb_actions))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
```

The Merge [API of Keras](https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.2.2/layers/core/#merge) are meant for merging image and image in my understanding. How do I bring together these different type of inputs?

Edit: Here my attempt on what I mean to do. I want to train my agent at each time step with one image and one separate value. Since I think that the I should not pass the separate value together with the image in the conv network stream, I want to have a second stream for the value and then bring the image and value network together in the end.

```python
INPUT_SHAPE = (119, 214)
WINDOW_LENGTH = 1

img_input = (WINDOW_LENGTH,) + INPUT_SHAPE

img = Convolution2D(32, 8, 8, subsample=(4, 4), activation='relu', input_shape=img_input)
img = Convolution2D(64, 4, 4, subsample=(2, 2), activation='relu', input_shape=img)
img = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, subsample=(1, 1), activation='relu', input_shape=img)
img = Flatten(input_shape=img)
img = Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=img)


value_input = (1,2)
value = Flatten()(value_input)
value = Dense(16, activation='relu')(value)
value = Dense(16, activation='relu')(value)
value = Dense(16, activation='relu')(value)

actions = Dense(nb_actions, activation='linear')(img)(value)


model = Model([img_input, value_input], [actions])
```

Either `img = Convolution2D(32, 8, 8, subsample=(4, 4), activation='relu', input_shape=img_input)` or `img = Convolution2D(32, 8, 8, subsample=(4, 4), activation='relu')(img_input)`
style does not work.

Also I do not know how to bring the stream together in `actions = Dense(nb_actions, activation='linear')(img)(value)`

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that you will have to use not the Sequential but the Model class API.

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, i hope the following code will help you

```python
inp = Input((1, 120, 215))
x = Convolution2D(32, 8, 8, subsample=(4, 4), activation='relu')(inp)
x = Convolution2D(64, 4, 4, subsample=(2, 2), activation='relu')(x)
x = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, subsample=(1, 1), activation='relu')(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)

x_a = Dense(nb_actions, name='a', activation='linear')(x)
x_b = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax', name='b')(x)

model = Model([inp], [x_a, x_b])
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.001), loss=['mse', 'categorical_crossentropy'], metrics=['accuracy'],
         loss_weights=[.0001, 1.]) #adjust loss-Weights 
model.fit(train_feat, [train_labels_a, train_labels_b], batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=3, 
         validation_data=(val_feat, [val_labels_a, val_labels_b]))
```

EDIT
If you need 2 inputs models and 1 output, try this:

```python
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Concatenate

image_model = Sequential()
image_model.add(Convolution2D(32, 8, 8, subsample=(4, 4), input_shape=input_shape))
image_model.add(Activation('relu'))
image_model.add(Convolution2D(64, 4, 4, subsample=(2, 2)))
image_model.add(Activation('relu'))
image_model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, subsample=(1, 1)))
image_model.add(Activation('relu'))
image_model.add(Flatten())
image_model.add(Dense(512))
image_model.add(Activation('relu'))


value_model = Sequential()
value_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=values))
value_model.add(Dense(16))
value_model.add(Activation('relu'))
value_model.add(Dense(16))
value_model.add(Activation('relu'))
value_model.add(Dense(16))
value_model.add(Activation('relu'))

merged = Concatenate([image_model, value_model])

final_model = Sequential()
final_model.add(merged)
final_model.add(Dense(nb_actions, activation='linear'))
```

Comment: True, the Model class API is what I need. Your example code describes one input and two outputs. I will adapt this to 2 inputs (image and separate status values) and one output (nb_actions).

Comment: Please see Edit